# Is there any way to use get with object instead of dict in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

If i have dictionary the this works fine

`value = d.get(key, "empty")`

But if `d` is my `django model object` then i get this

> object has no attribute 'get'

How can i fix that. I want have same behaviour like dict to get empty if key does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `getattr()`:

```
value = getattr(d, key, "empty")
```

Another option is to direct access to the object's `__dict__`:

```
value = d.__dict__.get(key, "empty")
```

But I suggest to use the `getattr()`.

**UPDATE**: Note that `getattr(some_dict, key)` is not the same as the `some_dict.get(key)`.  `getattr()` gets the object's attribute but not the value of the dict.

Comment: Is it possible to have some function defined in base class so that if i just use  `d.key` then i get the above behavior

Comment: I tried above and again got this error `'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`. i tried this `getattr(p.user, 'name', "")`

Comment: Yes, you get override the behaviour of the `getattr()` by defining `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` methods: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Comment: This is the full error line `File "report.py", line 46, in handle
    user.name = getattr(p.user, ’name', "")
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute ’name'`

Comment: The error is in the `user.name` expression.  As far as I understand `user` is a dict so you should write `user['name'] = getattr(p.user, ’name', '')`